# Error "copy-dependencies" in maven

Tags: java, maven, m2e, maven-dependency-plugin

I want copy lib dependencies in maven into lib directory when install project.
I used that in my pom file.

```xml
<project>
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>    
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But it's error following:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
maven-dependency-plugin (goals "copy-dependencies", "unpack") is not supported by m2e. pom.xml  /jasperreports-test line 60 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

I tried fix it.
This is pom file in my project.

```xml
<project>

    <groupId>com.vccorp.adtech</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserAgentService</artifactId>
    <version>14.06.201</version>

    <name>UserAgentService</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>            
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/lib
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

But when install It errors following:

```
> [INFO] Building UserAgentService 14.06.201 [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
> See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
> details. Downloading:
> http://222.255.27.149:8081/nexus-maven/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/1.0/maven-dependency-plugin-1.0.pom
> [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 4.716s [INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 26 11:55:06 ICT
> 2012 [INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:1.0 or
> one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
> descriptor for
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:1.0: Could not
> transfer artifact
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:1.0 from/to nexus
> (http://222.255.27.149:8081/nexus-maven/content/groups/public/):
> Connection refused: no further information to
> http://222.255.27.149:8081/nexus-maven/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/1.0/maven-dependency-plugin-1.0.pom
> -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using
> the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more
> information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the
> following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

This is my setting.xml file.

```xml
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>mjx-snapshot</id>
            <username>deployment</username>
            <password>deployment123</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>vccorp-repository</id>
            <username>editor</username>
            <password>edxmaven</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://192.168.5.149:8081/nexus-maven/content/groups/public/</url>
        </mirror>       
        <mirror>
            <id>public_nuxus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <!--this profile will allow snapshots to be searched when activated -->
            <id>public-snapshots</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>public-snapshots</id>
                    <url>http://public-snapshots</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>public-snapshots</id>
                    <url>http://public-snapshots</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <!-- <activeProfiles> <activeProfile>central</activeProfile> </activeProfiles> -->
</settings>
```

Please help me!

Comment: Why are you trying to copy dependencies ? If you just want to make an executable jar, take a look at maven-assembly plugin.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Rémy. I used maven-assembly plugin but sometime I want using copy-dependencies for some reasons.

Comment: I used it myself for this purpose. Nevermind, at this moment, I don't have any clue (without studying it deeper myself) to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this bug. The repository that I'm using is not available therefore Maven can not download the plugins.

Answer (score 2):

For me it looks like it's trying to find version `1.0` of `maven-dependency-plugin` which [isn't available in Maven Central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). Use `2.4` version as you did in first POM snippet you had pasted and it should be OK.